# How to fix this Add coding of the map I have a bug

Tags: android, dictionary, webview, geo

i am new android devloper
My webview is working well.
My webview map goes open. How to take it to the map application. I get an error due to some coding add. If you go to google and click on the map, you will be taken to the map.How to fix this and how to move it to the map

The image below shows some error
[image]

```
public class WebAppInterface implements NetworkMonitorCallbacks, AuthenticationCallbacks {
        private final WebView webView;
        private final String url;
        private boolean webAppLoaded = false;
        private boolean isOnline = false;
    
        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        public WebAppInterface(final Activity context, final String url, Bundle previousState, AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
            this.url = url;
            context.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            webView = (WebView)context.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            if (previousState != null) {
                webView.restoreState(previousState);
            } else {
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    
    
    
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
                        if(url.contains("geo:")) {
                            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
                            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                            if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                startActivity(mapIntent);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
    
    
    
    
                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                        Log.v(TAG, "Error on loading URL: " + failingUrl);
                    }
                });
                webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                        Log.v(TAG, cm.message() + " -- From line "
                                + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                                + cm.sourceId() );
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
                webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
                webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
                webView.addJavascriptInterface(authenticationProvider, "AuthenticationProvider");
                //// Geo location //////////
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
    
                webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                        // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);
                        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
                    }
                });
    
            }
    
        }
    
    
        public void load() {
            Log.v(TAG, "Loading URL: " + url);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            webAppLoaded = true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void networkStatusChange(boolean isOnline) {
            this.isOnline = isOnline;
            Log.v(TAG, "Network status changed to: " + isOnline );
            if (isOnline) {
                webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
                if(webAppLoaded) {
                    callJavaScript("goOnline");
                } else {
                    load();
                }
            } else {
                webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
                if(webAppLoaded) {
                    callJavaScript("goOffline");
                } else {
                    load();
                }
            }
        }
    
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void error(String error){
            Log.v(TAG, "WebViewError: " +  error);
        }
    
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void log(String message) {
            Log.v(TAG, "WebViewConsole: " +  message);
        }
    
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void getNetworkStatus() {
            if (isOnline) {
                callJavaScript("goOnline");
            } else {
                callJavaScript("goOffline");
            }
        }
    
        public void callJavaScript(String methodName, Object...params){
            boolean firstParam = true;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("javascript:try{");
            stringBuilder.append(methodName);
            stringBuilder.append("(");
            for (Object param : params) {
                if (!firstParam) {
                    stringBuilder.append(",");
                    firstParam = false;
                }
                if(param instanceof String){
                    stringBuilder.append("'");
                    stringBuilder.append(param);
                    stringBuilder.append("'");
                }
            }
            stringBuilder.append(")}catch(error){Android.log(error);}");
            Log.v(TAG, "Calling javascript: " + stringBuilder.toString());
            webView.loadUrl(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    
        public void saveState(Bundle bundle) {
            webView.saveState(bundle);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationInfoReady(AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo) {
            callJavaScript("onAuthenticationInfoReady", authenticationInfo.toJSON());
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onAccessTokenReady(String token) {
            callJavaScript("onAccessTokenReady", token);
        }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `getPackageManager()` and `startActivity()` you need to use a context, so you could use the context from your `WebAppInterface` method or use the `WebView view` parameter from your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and use it like

```
view.getContext().getPackageManager()
view.getContext().startActivity()
```

### Documentation

[`PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager)

> Class for retrieving various kinds of information related to the application packages that are currently installed on the device. You can find this class through Context#getPackageManager.

[`startActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivity(android.content.Intent))

> To be of use with Context.startActivity(), all activity classes must have a corresponding  declaration in their package's AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: SIf you go to google in web view and click on map then the intent application map will be stuck